# ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 1: No database selected

Tags: mysql, bash

I want to update some table with bash instead of mysql terminal directly.
The normal way is to ebedded sql command in bash with here doc string.

```
mysqlword="xyzzy"
tmpdb="yyyy"
mysql -u root -p$mysqlword  <<EOF
    USE ${tmpdb};
    UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'domain1', 'domain2');
EOF
```

Try another way to do the same job.

```
mysqlword="xyzzy"
tmpdb="yyyy"
mysql -u root -p$mysqlword  -e"USE ${tmpdb};"
sql="UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'domain1', 'domain2');"
mysql -u root -p$mysqlword  -e"$sql"
ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 1: No database selected
```

I have selected database with `mysql -u root -p$mysqlword  -e"USE ${tmpdb};"` before `mysql -u root -p$mysqlword  -e"$sql"`,how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix/simplify this in a couple of ways:

1. By removing the separate USE statement.
2. By removing the user credentials from the command line.

Reference the database name directly in the UPDATE statement:

```
sql="UPDATE wp_posts SET ${tmpdb}.post_content = replace(post_content, 'domain1', 'domain2');"
```

If you have version mysql >= 5.6.6, use `mysql_config_editor` to put the login credentials into a .mylogin.cnf file. It'll save typing and the password will be encrypted.

e.g.

```
mysql_config_editor --login-path=root --user=root --host=localhost --password
```

Once set, your bash command would then be simpler (and safer)

```
tmpdb=yyyy
sql="UPDATE wp_posts SET ${tmpdb}.post_content = replace(post_content, 'domain1', 'domain2');"
mysql --login-path=root -e "$sql"
```

or, since the variable aren't really necessary here,

```
mysql --login-path=root -e "UPDATE wp_posts SET yyyy.post_content = replace(post_content, 'domain1', 'domain2');"
```

Comment: No, MariaDB doesn't support this feature.

Comment: @scrapy Quite right, mariadb doesn't support this, but then the post was tagged mysql and not mariadb. The point was about getting the credentials off the command line. If it was a one-off task, the user may have been much better off using -p on its own and typing in the password manually - we don't know enough about the circumstances to say for sure. While we're at it, they probably wouldn't want to use the root account for this sort of interaction with the database either.

Answer (score 2):

You have to `USE` the database every time you open a connection. So you have to combine the two commands:

```
mysqlword="xyzzy"
tmpdb="yyyy"
sql="USE ${tmpdb}; UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'domain1', 'domain2');"
mysql -u root -p$mysqlword  -e"$sql"
```